# jquery mobile listview wrapping after image

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create consistent size images down the left of a list view. I can achieve what I want with background-size: cover;

For some reason the text to the right wraps to the next line.

Here's an example of the problem. The 1st line item simply displays the image .. the problem is that it's an odd size and I want it to be a square. So I'm using a DIV + background-size: cover; on the second list item to show what I want to achieve .. but then the text bumps to the next line ... does anyone know how I can keep the text to the right of the image?

http://jsfiddle.net/67gtsk7k/

```
<div data-role="page"> 
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview"> 
        <li><a href="/somepage1"><img src="http://assets0.livecache.net/L6/3/IOGLO/835119998/188973969/2014-09-19_20.30.48_200px.jpg" /><h2>Some detail here</h2><p>Sub Detail</p></a></li>
        <li><div style="width: 70px; height: 70px; background-image: url(http://assets0.livecache.net/L6/3/IOGLO/835119998/188973969/2014-09-19_20.30.48_200px.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div><a href="/somepage1"><h2>Some detail here</h2><p>Sub Detail</p></a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apply the following style:

```
.ui-li .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li { 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And give your div that has the background image a style of `display: inline-block;`

Elements with `display: block;` is treated as a full-width element to its container size rather than a width of its own.

---

**EDIT BASED ON YOUR NEW PROBLEM**

So once you switched versions, things are configured differently because they now have different labelling systems as well as styles.

Regardless, the issue was that you initially want your image to be inside your `<a>` tag (where your text is in) and you probably should wrap your text in a `div` or `span` so that you can style it as `display: inline-block;` together.

http://jsfiddle.net/8houxwnt/1/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Of course I'm using the newer version of jquery mobile and it's not behaving the same way, but i'll post that as a separate question because your answer was 100% correct. Thank!

Comment: Here's the corrected version for those interested - http://jsfiddle.net/WarrickF/86ahn7du/ ... however when I switched to the latest jquery mobile it broke? http://jsfiddle.net/WarrickF/8houxwnt/

Comment: This is some quality service I'm giving you. Anyways, answer has been updated.